# Shift Reduce Conflict

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm having trouble fixing a shift reduce conflict in my grammar. I tried to add -v to read the output of the issue and it guides me towards State 0 and mentions that my INT and FLOAT is reduced to variable_definitions by rule 9. I cannot see the conflict and I'm having trouble finding a solution.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

%token INT FLOAT
%token ADDOP MULOP INCOP
%token WHILE IF ELSE RETURN
%token NUM ID
%token INCLUDE
%token STREAMIN ENDL STREAMOUT
%token CIN COUT
%token NOT
%token FLT_LITERAL INT_LITERAL STR_LITERAL


%right ASSIGNOP
%left AND OR
%left RELOP

%%
program:    variable_definitions
      | function_definitions
      ;
function_definitions: function_head block
      | function_definitions function_head block
      ;
identifier_list: ID
      | ID '[' INT_LITERAL ']'
      | identifier_list ',' ID
      | identifier_list ',' ID '[' INT_LITERAL ']'  
      ;
variable_definitions: 
      | variable_definitions type identifier_list ';'
      ;
type:         INT
      | FLOAT
      ;
function_head: type ID arguments
      ;
arguments: '('parameter_list')'
      ;
parameter_list:
      |parameters
      ;
parameters:   type ID
      | type ID '['']'
      | parameters ',' type ID
      | parameters ',' type ID '['']'
      ;
block:        '{'variable_definitions statements'}'
      ;
statements:   
      | statements statement
      ;
statement:    expression ';'
      | compound_statement
      | RETURN expression ';'  
      | IF '('bool_expression')' statement ELSE statement
      | WHILE '('bool_expression')' statement 
      | input_statement ';'
      | output_statement ';'
      ;
input_statement: CIN
      | input_statement STREAMIN variable
      ;
output_statement: COUT
      | output_statement STREAMOUT expression
      | output_statement STREAMOUT STR_LITERAL
      | output_statement STREAMOUT ENDL
      ;
compound_statement: '{'statements'}'
      ;
variable:     ID
      | ID '['expression']'
      ;
expression_list: 
      | expressions
      ;
expressions:  expression
      | expressions ',' expression
      ;
expression:   variable ASSIGNOP expression
      | variable INCOP expression
      | simple_expression
      ;
simple_expression: term
      | ADDOP term
      | simple_expression ADDOP term
      ;
term:         factor
      | term MULOP factor
      ;
factor:       ID
      | ID '('expression_list')'
      | literal
      | '('expression')'
      | ID '['expression']'
      ;
literal:      INT_LITERAL
      | FLT_LITERAL
      ;
bool_expression: bool_term
      | bool_expression OR bool_term
      ;
bool_term:    bool_factor
      | bool_term AND bool_factor
      ;
bool_factor:  NOT bool_factor
      | '('bool_expression')'
      | simple_expression RELOP simple_expression
      ;
%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of a `program` is that it is either a list of variable definitions or a list of function definitions (`program: variable_definitions | function_definitions;`). That seems a bit odd to me. What if I want to define both a function and a variable? Do I have to write two programs and somehow link them together?

This is not the cause of your problem, but fixing it would probably fix the problem as well. The immediate cause is that `function_definitions` is one or more function definition while `variable_definitions` is zero or more variable definitions. In other words, the base case of the `function_definitions` recursion is a function definition, while the base case of `variable_definitions` is the empty sequence. So a list of variable definitions starts with an empty sequence.

But both function definitions and variable definitions start with a `type`. So if the first token of a program is `int`, it could be the start of a function definition with return type `int` or a variable definition of type `int`. In the former case, the parser should shift the `int` in order to produce the `function_definitions` base case:; in the latter case, it should immediately reduce an empty `variable_definitions` base case.

If you really wanted a program to be either function definitions or variable definitions, but not both. you would need to make `variable_definitions` have the same form as `function_definitions`, by changing the base case from empty to `type identifier_list ';'`. Then you could add an empty production to `program` so that the parser could recognize empty inputs.

But as I said at the beginning, you probably want a program to be a sequence of definitions, each of which could either be a variable or a function:

```
program: %empty
       | program type identifier_list ';'
       | program function_head block
```

---

By the way, you are misreading the output file produced by `-v`. It shows the following actions for State 0:

```
INT    shift, and go to state 1
FLOAT  shift, and go to state 2

INT       [reduce using rule 9 (variable_definitions)]
FLOAT     [reduce using rule 9 (variable_definitions)]
```

Here, `INT` and `FLOAT` are possible *lookaheads*. So the interpretation of the line `INT       [reduce using rule 9 (variable_definitions)]` is "if the lookahead is `INT`, immediately reduce using production 9". Production 9 produces the empty sequence, so the reduction reduces zero tokens at the top of the parser stack into a `variable_definitions`. Reductions do not use the lookahead token, so after the reduction, the lookahead token is still `INT`.

However, the parser doesn't actually do that because it has a different action for `INT`, which is to shift it and go to state 1. as indicated by the first line start `INT`. The brackets `[...]` indicate that this action is not taken because it is a conflict and the resolution of the conflict was some other action. So the more accurate interpretation of that line is "if it weren't for the preceding action on `INT`, the lookahead `INT` would cause a reduction using rule 9."

Comment: that was a very informative answer, you really helped me understand.